# QLineEdit отсебятина

Tags: c++, qt

```
connect(ui->b1,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(on_b1_clicked()));

void MainWindow::on_b1_clicked()
{
    char b1 = '1';
    QString phone = ui->PhoneLineEdit->text().append(b1);
    qDebug() << phone;
    ui->PhoneLineEdit->setText("");
    ui->PhoneLineEdit->setText(phone);
}
```

при нажатии на кнопку 1 долно в окно qlineedit выводить 1 а он 11 пишет. Откуда он это берет?

Comment: А это весь код?

Comment: нет, но просто line edit(PhoneLineEdit) через дизайнер создал и qpushbutton(b1) так же. Далее connect...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй в самом начале поставить `ui->PhoneLineEdit->clear` Может у тебя где-то в GUI затесалась единичка

Comment: убрал сигналы к кнопкам и все заработало как надо. Наверное дизайнер уже сам все сделал а я еще раз в ручную добавил. Ну и в итоге он два раза слот прогонял